# Javascript onclick Popup, without showing href destination url

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, onclick

I tried many forums, but got no perfect answer. So i thought of Stackoverflow for an help. I don't know whether it is a perfect category for the question.

I want to hide href link that opens as a popup. Its quite difficult to express the exact question here. So i am pasting a link:

http://songspku.co/arjun-sanam-ho-ja-remix-feat-dj-shadow-mp3-song

There in the table list, MP3 and Play open up as a popup. But now the thing is that i want to hide the url so that no one can either open the link directly or by right click for an new tab. It must be popup or onclick returns as div.

Also here i am pasting a similar code (from emp3z.co) that i want, but no idea what to do.

```
<div id="download_link"><a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick="showDownload('1','6PqdnRXmz_E', 'sia suitcase extract','mp3')" rel='nofollow' id='dl1' class='download_now'><span><i class="fa fa-download"></i> DOWNLOAD MP3</span></a></div>
```

Can anyone help me out? Also i am using a popup plugin in the site as class="wp-colorbox-youtube" and class="wp-colorbox-iframe".

Comment: If it is anchor link, it can be opened in a new tab. Instead you can add a method on click of it and then redirect to the respective page or do what you have to do from the script.

Comment: I want the link to open up as a popup. But no direct link.

Comment: also it will be ok if the link returns as div on onclick, on that same page.

Comment: Ok, add an `onclick` function and control the popup from the javascript

Comment: can you please provide me an example for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you are expecting, using jquery-UI, you can do something like below :

```js
$("#dialog").dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  show: false,
  hide: false
});

var songsMeta = {"song1":{"url":"www.example.com/song1"},"song2":{"url":"www.example.com/song2"}}

var openPopup = function (id) {
  var thisSong = "Download this song from here : " + songsMeta[id].url;
  $("#dialog").empty().append(thisSong).dialog("open");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="dialog">
 Download Song from here : 
</div>

<button id="opener" onclick="openPopup('song1')">Download mp3</button>
<button id="opener" onclick="openPopup('song2')">Download mp3</button>
```

Comment: Ok... what about the ids? every url is different?

Comment: In the table there will be 10 different rows with different urls. so how can i use this?

Comment: You can either pass all the information in the onclick method or have mapping in the script to avoid having sensitive data in the html

Comment: yeah i got it... Thanks for the help. Let me try this.

Comment: Cool. Let me know if you are stuck anywhere :)

Comment: can you please show me the js code for atleast two buttons... lets say <button id="opener" onclick="openPopup('sdsdsdsdd')">Download mp3</button> and <button id="opener" onclick="openPopup('lkjoiuiou')">Download mp3</button>